# Tools::getValue('controller') Prestashop helper file

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to use this code in prestashop php file:

```
if(file_exists(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'pc_orderspanel/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name) && Tools::getValue('controller') != 'AdminProductGrid' && Tools::getValue('controller') != 'AdminProducts')
```

Somehow it is not working.

If I remove this part `&& Tools::getValue('controller') != 'AdminProducts'`  and use the code it is working:

```
if(file_exists(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'pc_orderspanel/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name) && Tools::getValue('controller') != 'AdminProductGrid')
```

How can I add: `&& Tools::getValue('controller') != 'AdminProducts'`

Is it possible to combine the 2 `Tools::getValue('controller')` ?

Thanks!

Luke

Answer (score 0):

Replace the condition with following code:

```
$cont_name = Tools::getValue('controller');
    if(file_exists(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'pc_orderspanel/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name) && in_array($cont_name, array('AdminProducts', 'AdminProductGrid')))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but not working as expected. I don;'t think " != " is included in your code..